# automatic text formatting with printf (basing on maxlength of each column)

Tags: awk

the input data have n columns delimeted with "|" like on example below:

```
121|234234|5345|2342342342432423
1|2342|2|2342
234|23|343|34214222
```

how to find max length of each column and use it later in printf formatting of the input which will work even when input data are changed in a future?

in command like:

awk -F'|' '..... { printf "%-**longestincol1**s %-**longestincol2**s %-**longestincol3**s %-s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4 }' ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Column

if you just want to have a pretty-printed output, you can use `column` e.g.

```
column -t -s'|' -o'|' file
```

However, it is not exactly fit your `printf` format. It does left-alignment.

### Awk

If you want to do it with awk, you can apply at least two approaches:

#### process the file once

You let awk go through the input once, calc the max widths during looping, save all lines in memory. At the end, `END{...}` you loop through the array to print.

#### process the file twice

First you let awk go through the file, just calculate max-width, and save into variables. In the second go, do format printing.

I didn't give working codes, but I hope I answered clearly. Also it would be helpful when you next time face the similar problem.

Comment: I think `-o` available with GNU column

Answer (score 3):

**Input:**

```
$ cat infile
121|234234|5345|2342342342432423
1|2342|2|2342
234|23|343|34214222
```

**Output:**

**With** `printf("%*s%s"`

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}FNR==NR{for(i=1; i<=NF;i++)wd[i]=wd[i]>length($i)?wd[i]:length($i);next}{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)printf("%*s%s",wd[i],$i,(i<NF?OFS:ORS))}' infile infile
121|234234|5345|2342342342432423
  1|  2342|   2|            2342
234|    23| 343|        34214222
```

**With** `printf("%-*s%s"`

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}FNR==NR{for(i=1; i<=NF;i++)wd[i]=wd[i]>length($i)?wd[i]:length($i);next}{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)printf("%-*s%s",wd[i],$i,(i<NF?OFS:ORS))}' infile infile
121|234234|5345|2342342342432423
1  |2342  |2   |2342            
234|23    |343 |34214222
```

**Better Readable:**

```
awk '
     BEGIN{
            FS=OFS="|"
     }
     FNR==NR{
          for(i=1; i<=NF;i++)
             wd[i]=wd[i]>length($i)?wd[i]:length($i);
             next
     }
     {
          for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
              printf("%*s%s",wd[i],$i,(i<NF?OFS:ORS)); 

     }
   ' infile infile
```

**Explanation**

Like [C/C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) Specifies how much space to allocate for the string

> `*` The width is not specified in the format string, but as an
>   additional integer value argument preceding the argument that has to
>   be formatted.

```
printf("%*s",5,"")
```

is same as

```
printf("%5s", "");
```